# Python OS X - get 'date added' info from file

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

Hello it's my first post.

I started doing some coding in `Python` on OS X today.

I've noticed that OS X has such thing as a `date added` which is the time the file was put into specified folder.

I'm trying to get that date as a `timestamp`, however none of types work.

I've tried all three I know:

```
st = os.path.getctime('Untitled.gif')
st1 = os.path.getatime('Untitled.gif')
st2 = os.path.getmtime('Untitled.gif')
```

But none of them shows what I need.
Maybe there's a way to get all metadata from file somehow and just pick the info I need.

Thanks

Comment: Similar question but within Mac terminal: [Access the file "date added" in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341670/access-the-file-date-added-in-terminal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this information with the [`mdls`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdls.1.html) command, called via [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess
st = subprocess.check_output(["mdls", "-name", "kMDItemDateAdded", "-raw", "Untitled.gif"])
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems `st_ctime` ([the time of most recent metadata change on Unix](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.html?highlight=os.stat_result#os.stat_result.st_ctime)) is the closest attribute to "Date Added" on Mac that the class `os.stat_result` offers—which at a time resembles "Date Added" for some files yet at another time *doesn't* for the same files!

```py
import os
import datetime


st_result = os.stat('Untitled.gif')
ts = st_result.st_ctime
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
print(dt)
```

Sample output:

```sh
2021-09-08 15:10:22.602768
```

If I wish to interpret `st_ctime` as "Date Added," I should manually check if it **correctly** holds "Date Added" for **all the intended files**—e.g. sorting the files in a *terminal* by `ctime` with `ls -ltc | head -n NUMBER_OF_LINES_I_WANT_TO_SEE`; then corresponding their order with the order I see on a *finder* sorted by "Date Added."

Answer (score 0):

Try `os.stat('Untitled.gif').st_birthtime`.  More info on `os.stat` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat).

Comment: Birthtime is file creation date, not the date added to the directory.