# Access the file "date added" in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

In my downloads folder on my Mac the files have a "Date Added" column.

I'm trying to create a script to move files that are older than x days to my trash folder.  The following works but it is pulling the files based on created/modified date, not the "Date Added" that I see from Finder.  Is there a way to display/use this "Date Added" field?

find /users/home/downloads -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -type f -exec mv "{}" /destination/ \;

It looks like with the STAT command you have to list the filename for it to work.

Comment: This question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123076/osx-how-to-get-the-creation-modification-time-of-a-file-from-the-command-lin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSX - How to get the creation & modification time of a file from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123076/osx-how-to-get-the-creation-modification-time-of-a-file-from-the-command-lin)

Comment: I have already searched these and I don't see where you can list files by the "added date"?

Comment: Isn't date created the same thing?

Comment: When I'm looking at this particular file it was downloaded or "Date Added" on 11/16/18 but the created date is 01/29/13.

Comment: Also the STAT command requires the file name be given whereas I just want a list of files over a certain age based on when they were downloaded.

Comment: @eckenrod - no, date created & date modified are not the same thing as date added. Date added is the date the file was added to the folder. Date created is the date the file was created and date modified is the date the file was changed. Moving it to a new folder isn't changing the file.

Answer (score 2):

"Date Added" is stored in the metadata attribute `kMDItemDateAdded`. From the terminal, it can be retrieved using the `mdls` command:

```
mdls -name kMDItemDateAdded <filename>
```

will return something like

```
kMDItemDateAdded = 2022-01-03 16:40:14 +0000
```

If you add `-name kMDItemFSName`, it will also return the file name and thus can be used with wildcards in the filname (or just `*`).

Limitation:

While this should be working for the scenario described in the question, it seems that `mdls` does not return this attribute for files that are excluded from Spotlight search scope, like for example files in Trash, even though they do have that attribute, as can be seen in Finder. So there is probably a better answer than this which covers all files, no matter if they are in the Spotlight index or not.

See also [How can I find out when a file had been moved to trash?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437475/how-can-i-find-out-when-a-file-had-been-moved-to-trash)

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I am leaving up this answer in case the distinction between "ctime" and "birthtime" is useful, but commenters and [this newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71264110/394431) have suggested that neither is actually always identical to the "Date Added" in Finder.

---

In the `stat` structure, "Date Added" is st_ctime (which is the "time of last change of file status information") while "Date Created" is st_birthtime.

Other Mac (really BSD) commands can access either of these.  For example
`ls -ltc Downloads | head`
will list the most recently "Added" files, while
`ls -ltU Downloads | head`
will list the most recently "Created" files.

Similarly
`find Downloads -maxdepth 1 -ctime -2`
will find files "Added" in the last 2 days, while
`find Downloads -maxdepth 1 -Btime -2`
will find files "Created" in the last 2 days.

I suspect the command you want is

```
find /users/home/downloads -maxdepth 1 -ctime +365 -type f -exec mv "{}" /destination/ \;
```

Note the use of `-ctime`.

Comment: Hey, I noticed that `ctime` does not always hold `Date Added` we normally see on Finder. If we want to use that as `Date Added`, it must change only when moving files to another directory. However, `ctime` seems to be updated even if we do certain actions to files other than moving them! In a case where I saw a conflict between `ctime` and `Date Added` on my files, I learned that the Python script in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30969532/4526384) yields correctly the `Date Added` we see on Finder.

Comment: `ls -ltc` uses the time when the file was last changed. Neither this nor the time when the file was created is what "Date Added" means, which is the time when the file was added to the folder. I doubt that "Date Added" can be displayed using `ls`.